# HTML & CSS Linking

Tags: html, css

Lets suppose, I have two HTML files with two paragraph tags. I want a different styling for both of them and I do not want to use inline CSS. Any help on how can I do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different class or id. You can understand them better: https://www.washington.edu/accesscomputing/webd2/student/unit3/module5/lesson1.html

Answer (score 1):

try to give a different class/id name to each paragraph and target each one in your CSS file

Answer (score 0):

Make the CSS document and in the `<head></head>` tags put this in:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourstylename.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add external style sheet and link with your html files.

**Styles.css**

```
/*
  Styles.css
*/

#photo1{
 /*
   Add your styling
 */

}
#photo2{
  /*
   Add your styling
 */
}
```

In your html files you can link the css file and add relavant css code by id.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <picture id="photo1">

    </picture>

  </body>
</html>
```